# Jquery Sortable images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I want to drag and drop images .

https://github.com/glekli/jQuery-Sortable-Photos

I used this example for drag and drop. I tried the same way but in my code its not working. I didn't any error too, then why its not working,I am stucking with this issue.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>{{config('app.name')}}</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
  .bg-dark
  {
    background: #00a1ff !important;
  }
  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link
  {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link
  {
    color:#fff;
  }
  @media(min-width: 992px)
  {
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link
    {
      padding-left: 1em;
      padding-right: 1em;
    }
  }

.card {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.card-5 {
  box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
  /*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Thumbnail Gallery (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/thumbnail-gallery)
 * Copyright 2013-2017 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-thumbnail-gallery/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

body {
  padding-top: 54px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 56px;
  }
}

</style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="font-family: 'Pacifico', bold;font-size: 24px"><b>Photo Collage</b></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">English
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Netherlands</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Spanish</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Italian</a>
            </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Italian</a>
            </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Italian</a>
            </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Italian</a>
            </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Italian</a>
            </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Italian</a>
            </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Italian</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div style="margin-top:15px;" class="container">
<br/><Br/>
          @include('message')
<div style="margin:5px;box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 10px #D3D3D3">
  <br/>
          <table style="text-align:justify" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="3">

            <tr>
              <td height="588px" rowspan="3" class="my-item"><img width="412" height="588px" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive" alt=""></td>
              <td height="268" colspan="2" class="my-item"><img width="203" height="268px" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive" alt=""></td>
              <td width="168" class="my-item"><img width="201" height="168px" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td width="168" class="my-item"><img width="201" height="168px" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive" alt=""></td>
                <td colspan="2" class="my-item"><img width="201" height="168px" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" class="img-responsive" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

            </tr>
          </table>
          <br/>
     </div>

    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Primjena Software Private Limited 2017</p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-sortable-photos.js"></script>

    <script>
      $('.my-container').sortablePhotos({
  selector: '> .my-item',
  sortable: true,
  padding: 2
});
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('needs');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated');
    }, false);
  }, false);
})();
</script>


  </body>

</html>
```

I have 5 frames with images inside. For alignment I used table td . I have coded for drag and drop or in sense of replacing images. Please anyone help me to get out of this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add a fiddle, we can help you better.

Comment: You are missing something i.e where is class 'my-container'

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jgtLjogt/2/ this is the fiddle @ali

Comment: Yeah I have added with my-container too

Comment: I tried hard but my code is not working with same library https://plnkr.co/edit/DpoWgsVJEERmsEi6qCAA?p=preview

Comment: @KavyaShree I personally suggest please use https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

Comment: But I couldn't see any drags for images in this library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157900/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-ankit-pandey).

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to solve this problem using library https://github.com/glekli/jQuery-Sortable-Photos.

But not done now.

But if wants to done the image drag and drop using [Jquery-sortable](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/)

I have created a jsfiddle for support http://jsfiddle.net/Lnoh2br9/2/

***Note:*** May be some time http://lorempixel imges not responding.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </li>    
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: @Kavya Shree Got that solution?

Comment: No its not sorting images as like previous plugin